# Best way to phrase a sentence with parenthesis

Tags: prepositions, parentheses

I'm not sure exactly how to ask this question without giving an example, so here it is. What's the best way to phrase something like this:

> Found 3 errors (and gave 2 suggestions) for 'Some Book'

If these were to be written separately, you would want to write "Found 3 errors **in** 'Some Book'" and "Gave 2 suggestions **for** 'Some Book'". However, I want to write it as tersely as possible, in a single sentence, but all these ways seem awkward to me:

1. Found 3 errors (and gave 2 suggestions) **for** 'Some Book'
2. Found 3 errors (and gave 2 suggestions) **in** 'Some Book'
3. Found 3 errors in (and gave 2 suggestions for) `Some Book'

I think the first is the best, but is there a correct way to have a compound statement like this?

Comment: Found, and gave suggested fixes for, two errors in *Some Book*.

Comment: Good, Jim, provided that the fixes were for the errors. But what if he found two flat-out errors for which he could not provide fixes, and suggested two fixes for non-erroneous gracelessnesses?

Comment: StoneyB is correct, the two errors and two suggestions are different. I'll edit the question to make this a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two suggested fixes you made were not for the three errors that you report having found, then you should **not** use a parenthetical remark. Parenthetical remarks are inessential additions to sentences. It seem to me that both remarks are essential and should be given equal weight in the sentence:

> Offered 2 suggestions for changes and found 3 errors in *Some Book*.